# Windows 7 resets wallpaper to one stored in "Windows Wallpapers" on startup

Tags: windows-7, boot, desktop-customization

For some bizarre reason every time I start my computer Windows sets a wallpaper from the Architecture pack in the Windows Wallpapers category. If I change the wallpaper to a custom one, Windows resets it on startup. Any idea what could be causing this? I'm using Windows 7 64 bits.

Comment: uninstall Asus SmartLogon and Asus Power4Gea (if you have )

Comment: What does that have to do with the wallpaper changing? I do have them installed, but I'm not going to uninstall Asus Power4Gear...